# Storing large amounts of text (strings) for later usage

Tags: json, vb.net, string, storage, large-files

I am writing a windows forms application in VB.NET that makes http requests and gets JSON responses.

I would like to store all these JSON responses in a file to read them at some point in the future (line by line) as if I am making the requests from the file instead of the website/API.

I would like the read operations to be as fast as possible, whereas the writing can be relatively slow. So the frequency of the http request can be as small as 1/second to 1/minute, whereas i would like to read the data very fast (I guess 500ms or less?)

Right now, I am simply writing each JSON string as a new line of text in txt file. However the strings are long and the files are getting very big very quickly.

Is there a better/alternative solution to storing these JSONs/strings in a compact form for fast reading later on?

Comment: Depends on the programming language and environment you're using.

Comment: You could try compressing the text as binary with GZip, then base64 encode it so that it can still be included as text in your JSON. Performance-wise though YMMV.

Comment: @Juhana I am using VB.net for windows applicaton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework has a built-in support that would allow to do this.

Basically, you will have to take you string and convert it to a byte array.  Then you will have to deflate (zip) your byte array and convert it to a base64 string.

```
Public Function ZipString(stringToZip As String) As String
    Dim returnValue As String = ""

    Using output As New MemoryStream()
        Using gzip As New DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress)
            Using writer As New StreamWriter(gzip, Encoding.[Default])
                writer.Write(stringToZip)
            End Using
        End Using

        returnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray())

    End Using



    Return returnValue

End Function
```

To get your original string, you do the opposite:

```
Public Function UnZipString(stringToUnZip As String) As String
    Dim returnValue As String = ""


    Using inputStream As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(stringToUnZip))
        Using gzip As New DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            Using reader As New StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                returnValue = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using


    Return returnValue

End Function
```

You will then be able to store the JSON as a zipped string and unzip it when you'll need it.

Comment: Yes.  You zip your JSON string and then your store it in a file (or DB).  Generally speaking, the Inflate / deflate performance is acceptable but you you will have to check if it fits your needs.

Comment: Just to clarify, does this mean less space is taken because the encoded string is shorter than the none encoded one?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would suggest giving a look at [NoSQL](http://www.couchbase.com/why-nosql/nosql-database) databases. These are databases that use a **non-relational** (no SQL) model to improve performance and some of them (like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson) are oriented in storing/retrieving json objects directly.

Another option would be to store json documents in a search server like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)  which could store [JSON objects directly](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON). This scenario would be more suitable if you want to search a large amount of JSON objects as if they were documents. Using Solr gives you great flexibility in the way the data are stored, and gives you great searching functionality.

You could take a look at the advanced approaches (NoSQL, Solr) and think if the learning and transition curve of using a new technology would return the time investment regarding performance benefits. I would **first try to use a relational database** and **only if my performance needs are so big then I would test a NoSQL approach**.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to give an indication of speed requirements.

Comment: I would still suggest using the simpler solution (relational model) and if there is a performance problem, then consider using a NoSQL option. The actual performance is related with many factors (disk speed, json size etc). As Steve McConell [suggests](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735619670?ie=UTF8&tag=lstse01-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0735619670) you should make no assumptions about performance. You should just measure it before making any decisions.

Comment: I've been doing some reading about SQL DBs. What I understand is that these would be just frameworks in which the data is stored and retrieved and the databases would be stored locally on my machine? Is it possible to set up the database on one machine and access it from another?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. This is the rule of thumb. There is a server machine where the database is hosted. All the applications acting as database clients connect to this machine (even if they are running on other machines) in order to access the database. There is no DBMS (database management system not being able to do that). Anyway, you should ask another question regarding this specific issue. If you told us which DBMS you are interested in, we could also tell you how to do it...

Comment: Efxaristo Pantelis :) I will most likely post a new question about this at some point.